# Oracle SQLDeveloper Database Diff functionality doesn't consider dependencies

Tags: oracle, deployment, diff, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on creating a deploy script to migrate new development from our dev server to our uat server.  Unfortunately, the devs that made the changes didn't script them out at they coded.  The easiest way for me to approach this is to use SqlDeveloper's database diff functionality.  It does a good job of highlighting the differences and creating a script that I can run on UAT.  However, I've noticed that it doesn't take into account any dependencies.  For example, a it will put a command to create a table below a table that references it in a foreign key constraint.  Because the referenced table doesn't exist yet, the first table create command fails.  I've seen this with views referencing packages, packages referencing packages, etc.  Is there any easy to way either 1) force sql to export in a "smarter" order or 2) manually calculate the dependencies (ex: querying USER_DEPENDENCIES, etc) so that i can manually sort the file of create commands without resorting to trial and error?  I guess we could consider purchasing a commercial product as long as it matched exactly what we are looking for.

Note: we will probably have to deploy to UAT multiple times in order to support testing by end-users.  I am trying to automate this as much as possible so I don't have to manually recreate this script every single time!

Thanks!

Comment: The more i start to think about this, the more it may be impossible to generate a perfect script.  Think of an example where Package_A.Procedure_B calls Package_X.Procedure_Y and Package_X.Procedure_X calls Package_A.Procedure_C.  Both bodies would fail regardless of the order you put them in.  Therefore, does it make sense to just run the script multiple times and eventually the base objects will get created and the dependency errors will slowly "go away"?  We won't be left with duplicate objects since existing objs that can't be replaced will generate a harmless error?

Comment: `Both bodies would fail regardless of the order you put them in.` That is not true. You can compile package specifications first and then compile the bodies. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS009) for details. Also there can't be duplicate objects with the same name. Either you issue `CREATE OR REPLACE` and object definition is replaced, or for objects that support only `CREATE` syntax the error is raised.

Comment: Ahhh, yes you are correct.  I did not even think about separating spec from body (and not putting one right after the other).  By doing all of the specs first, then doing all of the bodies i can avoid the one incorrect example I presented.  However, the problem still exists where sqldev produces files that do not respect dependencies.  I guess I shouldn't have had a question mark on the last sentence in my comment.  You are correct, we will NOT have duplicate objects, so running the migration script multiple times might generate warnings, but no other adverse effects (dups) would be had.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296835/2899629), may be you find some alternative to SQL Developer.